# Convert a non-deterministic Turing machine into a deterministic Turing machine

Tags: turing-machines, simulation

How can we systematically convert a non-deterministic Turing machine into a deterministic Turing machine that recognizes the same language?

Comment: Non-deterministic turing machines are exponentially more powerful than determisistic turing machines. 'nuff said.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Good point. What I meant to ask for was a machine that recognized the same language, not one that performed with the same complexity.

Comment: What research have you done?  Have you looked in a standard textbook on automata theory?  This is likely to be covered in most such textbooks.  We expect you to do some research before asking here.

Comment: @D.W. I had difficulty finding resources on-line about this question, so I figured that having an easy-to-find SE question about the topic would be helpful to others. I will, of course, reference my textbook for more help myself.

Comment: @JanDvorak You should be careful stating unproven claims as truth. Also, your comment does not relate to the question at all.

Comment: @Raphael concerning unproven - if I add "unless P = NP", is my statement true? Also, it does relate because it limits the kind of reductions possible. Did the asker have a polynomial reduction in mind? If so, then existence of such would imply P = NP.

Comment: @JanDvorak If you assume P != NP, I'm going to ask you what you mean by "exponentially more powerful". Also, I don't know what this assumption means for larger classes; does your claim hold for all levels in the hierarchy by this one assumption? Anyway, Kevin does not give any indication he has a complexity-theoretic point of view (let alone one focussing on polytime) in mind, therefore I wrote that your comment does not relate. The question is complete as it stands (if a bit thin).

Comment: Jan Dvorak's original comment was posted when my question was more ambiguous about what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The deterministic machine simulates *all* possible computations of a nondeterministic machine, basically in parallel. Whenever there are two choices, the deterministic machine spawns two computations. This proces is sometimes called dovetailing. The tape of the deterministic simulator contains a list of configurations of the nondeterministic one, and performs a step on each of these in turn. This requires quite some administration, and the capability to move aroud data when one of the simulated configurations extends its allotted space.

Comment: IOW, it's very difficult, but it's possible to do automatically.

Comment: It can be useful to visualize the space of possible computations of a non-deterministic machine on some input as (binary) tree. The deterministic machine just traverses the whole tree in a breadth-first fashion. (Constructing this machine explicitly is sure to be messy.)

Comment: @JanDvorak Conceptually, it's a quite simple idea. I think the simulation is easy enough to code in an higher programming language. It's just the compilation to TMs that yields "ugly" "code".

Answer (score 4):

a worthwhile question because the algorithm is not really so trivial to a neophyte and worth studying for its key/basic theoretical implications, and your question is not specifically limited to [recursive languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_language)! a key is to recognize the algorithm as a [breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) of a (possibly infinite) graph of all possible transitions, ie exploration of all edges of a graph in parallel so to speak. (exercise: explain why the similar graph-traversal algorithm, [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_first_search) cannot work.)

the construction is relevant to, and shows up in, the famous/fundamental Cook proof for the NP completeness of SAT. basically solutions of the SAT construction are 1-1 correspondence with NTM acceptance paths in P-time.

moreover there is significant theory (somewhat similar/analogous) of converting other nondeterministic machines to deterministic ones eg NFAs to DFAs. in general the complexity of the corresponding classes (deterministic vs nondeterministic ones) is open for many related questions.

see also

- [what are infinite graphs good for](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12553/what-are-infinite-graphs-good-for) tcs.se
- [Cook/Levin theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%E2%80%93Levin_theorem), wikipedia